# Windows 10 allow connection to unknown network w/o intervention

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-access

We pre-configure a miniPC (NUC type device, [Beelink M1](http://www.bee-link.com/Beelink-MiniPC-TV-BOX-81-1.html) specifically although I don't think the device itself is relevant) to access equipment remotely at customer's sites, it uses Windows 10 Home edition which is more than sufficient for our needs. We often ship these devices out, or have employees drop them off at customer sites, and all they need is power and a network connection that provides DHCP. Then our Bomgar remote access software allows us to log into the device and access our equipment.

The issue we are having is when they are connected to the remote network, it is not known to the device, so it doesn't connect to it until someone connects a keyboard, mouse, and monitor and logs in locally, at that time Windows has a notification that a new network is detected and asks if the device should be discoverable or not. Regardless of the answer, once an option is selected the device connects to the network and our Bomgar remote access client connects back to our server.

My question is, how in Windows 10 can I bypass this restriction and just tell the device that no matter what network it connects to, known or unknown, to always be undiscoverable and connect immediately without having to have someone actually log in to the device? The end result is to be able to ship these anywhere, and have anyone connect it with an power and an Ethernet cable to any network with DHCP and Internet access, and have it immediately come online without intervention by a user.

Comment: I assume you are not an Administrator on this machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am... The account we have preconfigured has local admin access. When I say "pre-configured" it means our staff configures them from a new box with the necessary software, not pre-configured from the manufacturer.

Comment: You should be able to add the network manually with a registry edit as a known trusted network by exporting the key from a device that already knows about the network.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess I don't really understand what your referring to, this is not a wireless network but hard wired Ethernet... We do not have access to other computers on the network, our equipment is Linux servers or proprietary telecom servers. This is something unique to Win10 that requires "approval" to connect to a new network, our older Intel NUC boxes that had Win7 never had this issue.

Comment: Windows every since Windows XP has asked you to declare if a LAN/WAN network is public or private.  What is happening on Windows 10 isn't new.

Comment: @Ramhound Except in Windows 7 there was option to "Do this for all networks in the future" and for these devices we would always do that the first time... Window 10 does not seem to have that option. Windows 7 would still allow connection to originate from the device whether or not the network was marked as private or pubic in the GUI.